# Select rows from a DataFrame using .loc and multiple conditions and then show the row corresponding to the min/max of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know how to select data using .loc and multiple conditions, like so:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == True)&(df['B'] == 'Tuesday')]
```

But from the result of this I can't figure out how to show the entire row corresponding to the min (or max) taken on one other column of numbers, 'C'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

for columns:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == True)&(df['B'] == 'Tuesday')].apply(max, axis=0)
```

for rows:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == True)&(df['B'] == 'Tuesday')].apply(max, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['A'] == True)&(df['B'] == 'Tuesday')]

df2.loc[df2.C == df2.C.min(), :]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `idxmin` or `idxmax` functions.

[Docs for the idxmin function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html#pandas.Series.idxmin): "Return the row label of the minimum value. If multiple values equal the minimum, the first row label with that value is returned."

So, if you
`df.loc[((df['A'] == True) & (df['B'] == 'Tuesday')).idxmix()]`, this will return the row which has the minimum value for column C.

Comment: I have more columns than 'C'. I think that's why this method doesn't work. How do I specify on which column to do the .idxmax?

Comment: I meant to say several other columns besides 'A','B', and 'C'.

Comment: You're right. I guess @Nathaniel's answer fits your needs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'A': [True,False,True,True],
          'B': ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Tue'],
          'C': [1,4,5,1],
          'D': [10,20,30,40]})

print(df.query(""" A == True and B == 'Tue' and C == C.min() """))

      A    B  C   D
3  True  Tue  1  40
```